# [ Install Library Pyes in PyCharm ]

Tags: python, pycharm, pyes

I am installing Pyes in Python. 
I installed pyes in anaconda.

[image]

But I haven't find library Pyes in PyCharm

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI4dI.png): Picture when install Anaconda

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBlgR.png): Picture when find in PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I can see the library in my PyCharm interpreter window :

[image]

Considering closing the PyCharm and reselecting the project interpreter, also my Python version is 3.6

Comment: Ok , Thanks you , I find the solution+